# How to search different data from two same structure table from two same structure database?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I wanna search data that is different from each other.
I don't know how to link table in two database to search different data.
For example....
tblCustomer in Database1 has all data
tblCustomer in Database2 has some data that contain in Database1
I want to search which data does not contain in Database 1.

Answer (score 0):

In single query one cannot fetch data from two different databases.You may take data in dataset and perform your operation.

Comment: I guess I must be imagining SQL Server's four-part naming scheme then, which allows you to write even cross-server queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a three-part name to reference objects in another database (or four part if its also on another server/instance). Something like:

```
SELECT * --TODO, name columns
FROM
     tblCustomer c
        left join
     Database1..tblCustomer c_not
        on
           c.CustomerID = c_not.CustomerID --TODO - Actual match conditions
WHERE
    c_not.CustomerID is null --Only select rows where no match occurred.
```

(Here, I've assumed that the query is running in `Database2` and that `tblCustomer` in `Database1` is in the default schema)